# R replace value in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has a few variables, datem, seriesid and price.

For a given seriesid e.g. series 1000 I want to change the price at a certain datem (note datem = year(date)*12 + month(date)).

I have tried:

```
df$price[df$seriesid==114051 & ((df$datem == (1888*12+4))||(df$datem==(1888*12+3)))] <- 10.0
```

However, this replaces all my datem values to the same datem and replaces all my seriesids with 114051.

Does anyone have an easy way to replace specific values within my dataframe (it is a large dataframe).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dataset is voluminous, `data.table` is a good option. You can use conditional replacement thanks to the `:=` operator (update by reference)

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[id==114051 & (datem %in% c(1888*12+3, 1888*12+4))], price := 10.0]
```

The `dplyr` equivalent solution would be:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(price = if_else(id==114051 & (datem %in% c(1888*12+3, 1888*12+4)), 10, price)
```

It is likely to be slower than the first solution

Comment: Hi Linog thank you for answering. Your answer did not work due to the double |. 

What worked now was: 
x <- x[seriesid==114051 & (datem==(1888*12+4)|datem==(1888*12+3)), price:=11]

Comment: ok I had just copied-past your logical condition. I propose you a `%in%` solution in my edit that avoids using `OR` operator